# placing html element inline in responsive layout method

Tags: html, css

I want to place image, arrow , title and input textbox in particular way as in image.

1. Puting stlye tag in `hr` or `td` is not good practice, right? It did not help even
2. To keep space between `tr` only `<br/>`is option or any better way is possible?
3. How to keep space between arrow, title, textbox without using `&nbsp`

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/u7AjH/2/

I want to display content like this:

[image]

css:

```
.content > .container {height: 100%;}
.img-container1 { float:left; height:80% !important; width:40%}
```

Comment: Need to work on the attached fiddle or need to explain you on the attached wiki image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/u7AjH/4/

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/931x754"  alt="..." class="img-responsive img-rounded" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                            =>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                            Text Here
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                            =>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" >
                            <textarea style="height:200px" type="text" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                            Text Here
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                            =>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                            Text Here
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                  
         </div>
     </div>    
</div>
```

Although its not that good because I made it just now but i think it can help you.

You may use the grid system of bootstap in order for you to make a responsive grid.

Take a look with this documentation and you will learn more about bootstrap.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

I hope it can help you.

Comment: how can i place margin between each row? `.row { margin-bottom: 1%;}` is this correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve by adding margin as per your requirement.

try this:

```
.container div{
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="img-container1">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/931x754" alt="..." class="img-responsive img-rounded">
                </div>
                <div class="text-container">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Arrow
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="title" />
                            </td>
                            <td>Title</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Arrow
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <textarea name="textArea"></textarea>
                            </td>
                            <td>Title</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Arrow
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="title" />
                            </td>
                            <td>Title</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Arrow
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="title" />
                            </td>
                            <td>Title</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Arrow
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="title" />
                            </td>
                            <td>Title</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

.content > .container {height: 100%;}

.img-container1 { float:left; height:80% !important; width:40%}

.img-container1 img {max-width: 100%;}

.text-container {float: left; height: 80% !important; width: 60%}

.text-container table tr{height: 50px;}

.text-container table tr td:first-child{width: 10%;text-align: center;}

.text-container table tr td{width: 40%;}

.text-container table tr td:last-child{width: 10%;text-align: center;}

.text-container table tr td input{width: 100%;}

.text-container table tr td textarea{width: 100%;height: 200px;resize: none;}

**Working Example**
http://jsfiddle.net/3vSyL/